# How do I include DLL from project folder

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How do I set it up in Virtual Studio so that I can include a DLL file from my project path?  This is nessesasry because the 3rd party software I am referencing have different version of the same file, so I thought I would rename them and put it in my project as an asset.

EDIT:  Forgot to mention that I would like the path to be relative to the project folder, because it's in source control.  So the "Browse for DLL" option is not very optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Forgot to mention that I would like the path to be relative to the
>   project folder, because it's in source control. So the "Browse for
>   DLL" option is not very optimal.

If you open up the project file in a text editor, you can see that the "hint path" stored when adding a reference by browsing to a dll on the same drive is a relative path. So, "Browse for DLL" should work fine for your situation.